# How do I randomize egrep results in Mac OS

Tags: shell

I want to the take all the words from the dictionary with at least 6 characters, randomize the order of the words and store it in a text file.

I have tried following command but the sort -R option is not available in Mac.

Following command is working

```
egrep -i "^.{6,}$" /usr/share/dict/words | sort -r >words.txt
```

`sort -r` (reverse sort) is working but `sort -R` (random sort) is not working

Following command is not working

```
egrep -i "^.{6,}$" /usr/share/dict/words | sort -R >words.txt
```

Any other way that I can randomize the order of word listing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the `shuf` is there ?

Comment: No need for fancy egrep; just `grep '^......'` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this if you have `shuf` :

```
grep '^.\{6,\}' /usr/share/dict/words | shuf
```

Or with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) & [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
grep '^.\{6,\}' /usr/share/dict/words |
    perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle <>'
```

Or with only [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -ne '
    /^.{6,}/ and push @L, $_;
    END{print shuffle @L}
' < /usr/share/dict/words
```

`List::Util` was first released with perl v5.7.3, so it is installed with perl by default.

Comment: This won't output any 7 or more character words.

Comment: Added perl portable solution